# Exchange 2007 Server - Sender unable to send one recipient in the domain

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, smtp

I have a mail server that serves multiple domains. I have 2 users that use a specific domain. User A does not experience any issues when sending and receiving mail.  User B can send emails fine and receives emails fine from most external users. However when Sender1 sends an email to UserB , the sender gets a "#550 5.1.1 RESOLVER.ADR.RecipNotFound; not found ##" message. However Sender1 can send to UserA just fine. 
           I suspected that the issue was UserB was not setup correctly in exchange. After verification I determined this was not the issue. I then sent UserB emails from a number of external email addresses outside of our domain (Google, Yahoo, MSN) all of which were delivered, as they should have been.  I am now out of guesses as to what the issue could possibly be. Any takers?

Thanks

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem yet?  I'm running into the same message when one user gets e-mail from some external senders...

Answer (score 0):

Go into Powershell or the console and look at the properties (SMTP adresses) on both particular users.

It seems that one of the users might have gotten a wrong policy so that the correct smtp domain might not be listed on the mailbox.